# Reflecting table with specific columns returns "Can't create ForeignKeyConstraint on table"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to reflect a table, while loading only specific columns using `include_columns`. However, omitting a column that has a ForeignKeyConstraint causes an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3825, in _set_parent
    ColumnCollectionConstraint._set_parent(self, table)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3414, in _set_parent
    ColumnCollectionMixin._set_parent(self, table)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3371, in _set_parent
    for col in self._col_expressions(table):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3365, in _col_expressions
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3366, in <listcomp>
    table.c[col] if isinstance(col, util.string_types) else col
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 1213, in __getitem__
    return self._index[key]
KeyError: 'DiscountDefinition_FK'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../script.py", line 62, in <module>
    POSBillItem = Table('POSBillItem', metadata, include_columns=POSBillItem_columns, autoload_with=engine)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 607, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 602, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 677, in _init
    self._autoload(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 712, in _autoload
    conn_insp.reflect_table(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 795, in reflect_table
    self._reflect_fk(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 997, in _reflect_fk
    table.append_constraint(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 913, in append_constraint
    constraint._set_parent_with_dispatch(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 1046, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
    self._set_parent(parent, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3827, in _set_parent
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't create ForeignKeyConstraint on table 'POSBillItem': no column named 'DiscountDefinition_FK' is present.
```

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table

conn_string = engine.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username,
    password,
    host,
    port,
    db,
    query={"driver": "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server", "TrustServerCertificate": "YES"}
)
engine = create_engine(conn_string)

metadata = MetaData()

Table1_columns = [
    "PosBill_FK",
    "Quantity",
    "UnitPrice",
    #"DiscountDefinition_FK",
    #"originID"
]

POSBillItem = Table('POSBillItem', metadata, include_columns=Table1_columns, autoload_with=engine)
```

If i uncomment `"DiscountDefinition_FK"`, exception no longer occurs, though i get a warning:

```
.../script.py:62: SAWarning: Omitting index key for (originID), key covers omitted columns.
  POSBillItem = Table('POSBillItem', metadata, include_columns=POSBillItem_columns, autoload_with=engine)
```

If i uncomment `"originID"`, warning goes away as well.

Is there a way to avoid loading these columns without manually adding columns?

Comment: Maybe you just need to set [resolve_fks](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.resolve_fks) to `False`

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, i'm still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include_columns` option is not, in fact, honored by foreign key reflection - in a [discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8099) on GitHub it was confirmed to be a [bug](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8100).

As for warnings on index keys, they would probably be phased out in the future, but right now the options are: either including them or supressing the warning with `warnings` library.

UPD: Fixed in SQLAlchemy [1.4.38](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-04dc2abf7e7566c5218d2d18284015e9).